# Как превратить программу написанную на python 3.2 в исполняемый файл?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне интересно, как сделать из `py` файл `exe`, именно на питоне 3.2? Желательно получить инструкцию как этим пользоваться.

Comment: http://borisnote.wordpress.com/2010/01/04/python3-in-exe/

Comment: вай круто! спасибо! а почему вы написали в коментарий ане в ответ?

Comment: Воспользуйтесь PyInstaller-ом. https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cx_Freeze
http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/